# Android project not working if installed from apk

Tags: android, eclipse, apk

I have developed an Android application for tablets and if i run it from eclipse on a Samsung Note 10.1 or Samsung note PRO it is working.
But if i create apk file and install it on devices it doesn't work
I have set the permission in AndroidManifest
Anyone can help me?
It's a complex project that use external file, image (res directory), sharedPreferences
Thanks!!
And sorry for my english :)

Comment: You have to provide more information: what does that mean "doesnt work" ? It could not be installed ? It crashes? When ?

Comment: I found my problem! the problem was the implementation with dropbox API!someone have experience with dropbox API who can help me?

Comment: However, the application crashes when i try to open it